# Effectively counting records after join in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

This is what I am doing. I need to get number of records present in one dataset and not the other and then again join with a third dataset to get some other columns.

```
val tooCompare = dw
        .select(
          "loc",
          "id",
          "country",
          "region"
        ).dropDuplicates()

val previous = dw
        .select(
          "loc",
          "id",
          "country",
          "region"
        ).dropDuplicates()

val delta = tooCompare.exceptAll(previous).cache()
 
val records = delta
        .join(
          dw,//another dataset
          delta
            .col("loc").equalTo(dw.col("loc"))
            .and(delta.col("id").equalTo(dw.col("id")))
            .and(delta.col("country").equalTo(dw.col("country")))
            .and(delta.col("region").equalTo(dw.col("region")))
        )
        .drop(delta.col("loc"))
        .drop(delta.col("id"))
        .drop(delta.col("country"))
        .drop(delta.col("region"))
        .cache()
    }

 val recordsToSend = records.cache()
 val count = recordsToSend.select("loc").distinct().count()
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?
I am new to Spark. I am pretty sure I am missing something here

Comment: Why have you reassigned dataframe while using cache() function? You don't need to reassign the dataframe while using the cache function ```val recordsToSend = records.cache()``` .Also,for the records datarframe you can try ```records.alias("fst").join(second_df, your_joining_condition).select("fst.*")```

Comment: But how is this more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using SQL to make this more readable.

First, create Temp Views of the dataframes in question. Don't know exactly what data frames you have, so something like

```
dfToCompare.createOrReplaceTempView("toCompare")
previousDf.createOrReplaceTempView("previous")
anotherDataSet.createOrReplaceTempView("another")
```

Then you can proceed to do all your opertions in one SQL statement

```
val records = spark.sql("""select loc, id, country,region
              from toCompare c
              inner join another a
               on a.loc = c.loc  
                and a.id = p.id
                and a.country = c.country
                and a.region = c.region
             where not exists (select null
                                from previous p
                                where p.loc = c.loc  
                                 and p.id = p.id
                                 and p.country = c.country
                                 and p.region = c.region""")
```

Then you can proceed as before...

```
val recordsToSend = records.cache()
val count = recordsToSend.select("loc").distinct().count()
```

Comment: As per OP, the question is to solve the problem in an efficient way and not making it readable or in one-line. Even though the query is a one-liner, spark will create similar planning and tasks calculating the output using native code and spark.sql().

Comment: I agree.Somehow cache followed by count is not as fast I had hoped

Comment: If you only access the dataset once cache will possibly give a slight performance hit, not increase. Also remember Spark executes lazily so the cache line doesn't do anything, it's only cached during the line with the count operation

Comment: @Nick Yes, I understand that. However this is what I did. My question is, is there a better  way to do this. Cache may not work, but is there a way for faster exection?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's potentially some errors in the code you've pasted as tooCompare and previous are the same, + the third dataset join references deAnon but dw on the table....

For this example answer, assume your current table is called "current", previous is called "previous" and third table is "extra". Then:

```
val delta = current.join(
              previous, 
              Seq("loc","id","country","region"), 
              "leftanti"
            ).select("loc","id","country","region").distinct

val recordsToSend = delta
                    .join(
                      extra,
                      Seq("loc", "id", "country", "region")
                    )

val count = recordsToSend.select("loc").distinct().count()
```

This may be more efficient, but I'd appreciate you commenting as to whether it actually was!

Just as an aside: note that I'm using the Seq[String] as a join argument (this requires the column names to be identical on both tables, and won't produce two copies of the columns). However, your original join logic can be written a bit more succinctly, as follows (using my naming conventions):

```
val recordsToSend = delta
                    .join(
                      extra,
                      delta("loc") === extra("loc")
                        && delta("id") === extra("id")
                        && delta("country") === extra("country")
                        && delta("region") === extra("region")
                    )
                    .drop(delta("loc"))
                    .drop(delta("id"))
                    .drop(delta("country"))
                    .drop(delta("region"))
```

Even better would be to write a drop function that lets you provide more than one column, but I'm going really off topic now ;-)

Comment: Hi Nick. Thanks  for your edit and reply. How is `Seq` more efficient than `exceptall`

Comment: You mean antijoin, I'm using seq here as a more succinct way of specifying the join criteria. My idea is that your first set of dropDuplicates will do a shuffle first for each set of data, and then the exceptAll may possibly do a second shuffle (but probably doesn't) where as antijoin will certainly only do one shuffle. Anti join is also more directly doing what you want to do, it's possible spark have better optimisers for this query. There's every chance that there is no performance difference and I've just written your query more elegantly though! Let me know though.